# How do I factor out MySQL from API controller?

Tags: mysql, node.js

How do I move the MySQL related function into a `contractsService.js` file?

I'm getting an error:

> C:\code\firstdrafte2e\app.js:8 app.get('/contracts', GetContracts(req,
>   res));
>                                      ^
>
> ReferenceError: req is not defined

**contractsService.js**

```
exports = function GetContracts(req, res) {
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        con.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.query("SELECT * FROM " + config.DATABASE + ".Contracts", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //console.log(result);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }).then(rows => res.send(rows));
}
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


    app.use(express.static('client'));
    const config = require('./config')
    var GetContracts = require('./contractsService');

    app.get('/contracts', GetContracts());

    module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not passing (req,res) to your GetContracts function. You can create an anonymous function, assign to a variable and export it as below.

**contractsService.js**

```
  exports.GetContracts = function(req, res) {
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT * FROM " + config.DATABASE + ".Contracts", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //console.log(result);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}).then(rows => res.send(rows));
```

}

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('client'));
const config = require('./config')
var GetContracts = require('./contractsService');

app.get('/contracts', GetContracts);

module.exports = app
```